# Strange results drawing an image onto another image

Tags: c#, image, watermark, graphic

Given an image:

[image]

And a watermark:

[image]

And the code:

```
var originalImageBytes = originalFile.FileBytes();

// Draw watermark
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(originalImageBytes))
using(var originalImage = Image.FromStream(ms))
using (var watermark = Image.FromFile(Settings.FSO.RootNonPublicDirectory + "Images/Watermark/Watermark.png"))
using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(originalImage))
{
    g.DrawImage(watermark, 0, 0);

    using (var msOut = new MemoryStream())
    {
        originalImage.Save(msOut, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        return msOut.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Produces the following result:

[image]

Note, the dimensions are correct but a chunk of the bottom of the image is missing.

Right clicking and `save-as` saves this image onto my disk, looks corrupted:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?

Comment: try specifying the entire rect: `g.DrawImage(watermark, new Rectangle(destX, destY,  watermark.Width, watermark.Height));`

Comment: @Plutonix, same result.  Image in browser appears cropped, save as shows original image.

Comment: Solved the save-as problem showing a different image, was serving different bytes.  Have updated question.

Comment: I ran your code and it produces valid image, without any corruption.

Comment: You are not running that on mono by any chance?

Comment: Fixed, thanks for everyone that looked.  The page serving the content was sending the `content-length` header of the original image, not the watermarked one.

Sorry for wasting all your time!